# Multiple Validation Groups in c#

Tags: c#, validation

I have two validation groups: Group1 and Group2

I have an save button that needs to validate all validation groups.

But how can it be done server side?

```
<html>
<body>
     <form runat="server">
          <asp:textbox id="TextBox1" runat="server"/>
          <asp:requiredfieldvalidator ValidationGroup="Group1"
                                                       ErrorText="Need to Fill in Value 1  !"
                                                       ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                                                       runat="server"/>
            <asp:textbox id="TextBox2" runat="server"/>

            <asp:requiredfieldvalidator ValidationGroup="Group2"
                                                         ErrorText="Need to Fill in Value 2 !"
                                                         ControlToValidate="TextBox2"
                                                         runat="server"/> 

            <asp:button text="Group1" ValidationGroup="Group1" runat="server"/>
            <asp:button text="Group2" ValidationGroup="Group2" runat="server"/>

           <asp:ImageButton ID="Save" runat="server" OnClick="Save_Click"
            ImageUrl="/aspnet/Img/save_button.gif" 
            CommandArgument="Save"
            OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;" />
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**#First Edit**

```
protected void Save_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate("Group1");
    Page.Validate("Group2");

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        //validate page
    }
    else
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Msg", "alert('Stop.');", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Page.Validate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.validate?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_Page_Validate)? - "Instructs any validation controls included on the page to validate their assigned information"

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Thanks for help. Please see **#First Edit** in my question. The code not working.